# Cannot set option on inline date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

We are using a date picker inline, and I need to change the default property value of `false` to `true` for `todayHighlight`. The problem is that we are using the datepicker inline, so I cannot set it when we initialize it from jQuery.

Here is the view:

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Required By</label>
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(z => z.RequiredDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",
                new
                {
                    @class = "form-control datepicker"
                })
            <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this method on the `$(document).ready()`, but it did not work:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker("option", "todayHighlight", true);
```

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Any errors or alerts from Console?

Comment: Also, where do you define the original `.datepicker()`

Comment: Also, for this one in particular on this view, we use the data-provide datepicker attribute. This does not get called in javascript. It does it inline without the need. That is the issue.

Comment: You can see the usage here: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/    Maybe i will remove that way, and just init them all via javascript so i  can set the options.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not defined your DatePicker object, adjusting an `option` will fail.

You could try:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker().datepicker("option", "todayHighlight", true);
```

You can also do this like so:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

If you're still seeing issues, you will need to investigate any any alerts or errors that are being generated by your browser in it's Console.

Comment: I had already tried what you mentioned prior. I gave it a shot again and still no go. I did notice that once I trigger change event, so enter just one key, then it selects the current date. Then when I make it empty, it no longer selects anything. I want to not 'select' current dates, but just kind of 'grey or highlight with dull color'. That way the end user automatically sees what the current date is no matter what they hit or select. Can't seem to get it to work though. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: @Casey this is not a feature of the `datepicker()`. Your description is a bit unclear, but I think with CSS you could do something like indicate "today" without selecting it.

Comment: How would I go about that? I am seeing it is not a feature built into it. I also do not see anything in the output code rendered, to be able to add a class to today to give it a highlight or so the user always sees the current date highlighted but a different color then the blue highlighted for a day selected.

Comment: So what I need is this. As soon as the calendar opens the end user can see what the current date is, but select any date they want. Just not sure if I can even do it pragmatically as there is nothing unique for 'today'.